# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python

I am sending a SOAP request to my server and getting the response back. sample of the response string  is shown below:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env=http:////www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelop
.
..
..
<env:Body>
    <epas:get-all-config-resp xmlns:epas="urn:organization:epas:soap"> ^M
...
...
<epas:property name="Tom">12</epas:property>
> 
> <epas:property name="Alice">34</epas:property>
> 
> <epas:property name="John">56</epas:property>
> 
> <epas:property name="Danial">78</epas:property>
> 
> <epas:property name="George">90</epas:property>
> 
> <epas:property name="Luise">11</epas:property>

...
^M
</env:Body?
</env:Envelop>
```

What I noticed in the response is that there is an extra character shown in the body which is "^M". Not sure if this could be the issue.  Note the ^M shown!
 when I tried parsing the string returned from the server to get the names and values using the code sample:

```
elements = minidom.parseString(xmldoc).getElementsByTagName("property")      
myDict = {}
for element in elements:
  myDict[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.firstChild.data
```

But, I am getting this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'. May be its something to do with the "^M" shown on the xml response back!

Any ideas/comments would be appreciated,

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

[Edited to make clearer, and to suggest looking for an empty element]

Apparently, some of the elements returned by getElementsByTagName don't have a firstChild. This happens when the element is empty, as in

```
<epas:property name="Empty"></epas:property>
```

When minidom encounters that situation, it'll set "element.firstChild" to None. This is very likely what's happening to you.

Otherwise, it's hard to say what's happening, exactly, with only a fragment of the XML (and a broken one, at that), but you could try catching the exception and inspecting the element in question:

```
for element in elements:
    try:
        myDict[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.firstChild.data
    except AttributeError:
        print element, element.firstChild
```

Or, instead of simply printing the element, you could call the debugger (import pdb; pdb.set_trace()). Then you can see the element, and understand why it's giving you trouble.

BTW, the "^M" is simply a windows-style carriage-return. I adapted the xml fragment you pasted, to test locally, and the "^M" makes no difference whatsoever, minidom takes care of it.

So, check for an empty element, or use the try/except as I suggested. If you still can't tell what's going on, paste the complete XML string (at http://pastebin.com/, for example), I might be able to help.

Also, on a related note: once you've sorted out this issue, you can construct the dictionary with a list comprehension:

```
myDict = dict((element.getAttribute('name'), element.firstChild.data) for element in elements)
```

And, if you've determined that it is a matter of empty elements, you can skip them thusly:

```
myDict = dict((element.getAttribute('name'), element.firstChild.data) for element in elements if element.firstChild is not None)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right guys, Thanks! I can see loads of None values returned!! I wonder why would this happen! How can I skip these None values and continue to the end of the string? I tried the code you posted rbp above but getting invalid syntax for: for element in elements if element.firstChild is not None)

Comment: Perhaps you're not indenting correctly? Try to get everything in one line (I've updated my answer to reflect that)

Comment: BTW, the None values should occur whenever there's an empty element. Check your XML input.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter elements which the first child is None, it seems to be about the ^M indeed, it is probably being turned into a TextNode object, a blank one without data.

```
elements = minidom.parseString(xmldoc).getElementsByTagName("property")      
myDict = {}
for element in elements:
    if element.firstChild:
        myDict[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.firstChild.data
```

Comment: Cool guys!!Yes, this does the trick :-). Thanks a million! The only issue here is when I look for an element that has None value, I am getting TypeError but works just fine if the element has a value! May be I can assume the the search should return "" if the value is None!!! For example for the above xmldoc if modify Louise to return no value:
<epas:property name="George">90</epas:property>   
<epas:property name="Louise"></epas:property> 

if I search for George and Luise:
georgeVlaue = myDict['George'], the output will be 90. But:
LouiseVlaue = myDict['Luise'].  I get typeError.

Comment: Are you sure you get *TypeError*? You should get a KeyError, since the key "Louise" won't be in the dict (since element.firstChild was None and you skipped it).

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one of your elements has a firstChild that has been set to None, and therefore trying to access its .data results in an error.

I suspect that the trailing ^M is the problem. The element produced for the ^M is invalid, and/so it has no firstChild element.

You can get around this by checking to see whether firstChild is equal to None before you try to extract its .data member.

Comment: `^M` is just a carriage return. It's likely the data is coming from a Windows machine that uses Windows-style line endings (carriage return + line feed) instead of Unix-style endings (line feed), but it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: That's true. An element with firstChild == None is the problem nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry guys, need to go back to teh same issue above!! Yes sometimes the firstChild returns a None value, so how can I avoid getting error when the firstChild is None! I tried adding condition to avoid this but still getting the same Keyerror

Answer (score 0):

element.firstChild is None. Are you sure you don't want element.data? I would guess firstChild refers to the first child element of element rather than a text node.

Comment: No, you need firstChild. For the xml snippet that the original poster pasted, "[e.firstChild.data for e in elements]" correctly returns "[u'12', u'34', u'56', u'78', u'90', u'11']". e.data raises an error.

Comment: Yup checking the docs shows that I stand corrected. He needs to get at the text node inside the element.